# How to show all the label in the ListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have such data

```
data = Uncompress[FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CroxQ.png"],"Byte"]]]]
```

> `{{1323.9,1177.7}->1,{1408.1,967.3}->2,<<60>>,{1038.9,206.3}->63,{1164.83,161.333}->64}`

If I use the `ListPlot` it directly, I will just get some label but not all

```
ListPlot[data, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = Uncompress[
   FromCharacterCode[
    Flatten[ImageData[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/CroxQ.png"], 
      "Byte"]]]];
```

Using the option `ImageSize->Large` will show more labels.

```
ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

An even larger `ImageSize` will show all of the labels.

```
ListPlot[data, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 1200]
```

[image]